# Tween being delayed

Tags: lua, roblox, tween

For some reason my tween is playing after I get teleported, also my second tween is not playing at all.

Here is code:

```
print("Player Teleporting")

game.Workspace.Spawn.Portals.set1.portalgyuer.telepart.Touched:Connect(function(player)
    game.Workspace.Spawn.Portals.set1.portalgyuer.telepart.CanTouch = false
    print("touched")
    local frame = game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.Teleport.load
    frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(1,0,0,0),Enum.EasingDirection.Out,Enum.EasingStyle.Sine,0.3,true)
    wait(1.5)
    player.Parent.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(15.5, -40.5, 6499.5)
    wait(1.5)
    frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0,0,0,0),Enum.EasingDirection.In,Enum.EasingStyle.Sine,0.3,true)
    wait(3)
    game.Workspace.Spawn.Portals.set1.portalgyuer.telepart.CanTouch = true
end)
```

Please help!

Thanks,

Comment: Is this a `localscript` or `script`?